# How to convert XmlNodeList to Xmlstring to bind xml data with dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
XmlDocument objXmldoc = new XmlDocument();
objXmldoc.Load(txtBrowseFilePath.Text);    
XmlNodeList objxmlNodeList=null;
    objxmlNodeList = objXmldoc.SelectNodes(@"/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime/text()[starts-with(. , '" + dateTimePickerFromDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "')]]");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();         
ds.ReadXml(objxmlNodeList);
```

How to convert XmlNodeList to Xmlstring to bind xml data with dataset

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>
<LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382918</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130116164037</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Message</LogType>
    <LogFlag>RISLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>BaburaoLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>RISLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>RISLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>BaburaoLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
<LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382919</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130116164038</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>MACLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>MACLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>MACLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>MACLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>MACLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

Comment: Please add some sample xml where select nodes should be performed

Comment: ok nothing there. seems to be a long file path name problem. Check again at the end of my answer

Answer (score 2):

try such a function:

```
    private string XmlNodeListToString(XmlNodeList nodeList)
    {
        String returnStr = "";
        if (nodeList != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                returnStr += node.OuterXml;
            }

        }
        /*
        //I think this is not needed from Dataset.ReadXml
        returnStr = returnStr .Replace("&", "&amp;");
        returnStr = returnStr.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        returnStr = returnStr.Replace(">", "&gt;");
        returnStr = returnStr.Replace("'", "&apos;");
        returnStr = returnStr.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
        */


        return "<Root>"+returnStr+"</Root>";
    }
```

Also from your comments seems that you have a long file name issue.

try `objXmldoc.Load(@txtBrowseFilePath.Text);`

or if it does not succeed 
try something else like preceding filepath with `\\?\`  as i found out in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath)

For example, `"\\?\D:\very long path"`.

Comment: your solution is right itzortz but getting me error illegal characters in path

Comment: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Check again at the end of the answer

Comment: where i use  file path only loaded file in xdocument and get nodes in xml nodelist and apend to string ??

Comment: just saying that u should try objXmldoc.Load("\\?\"+txtBrowseFilePath.Text);

Comment: Final attempt objXmldoc.Load(@txtBrowseFilePath.Text); Also i am not quite sure if the @ is needed in your xapth expression in SelectNodes

Comment: @iltzortz  i hve used ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(strXML)); working fine for small size files but when i load 178MB file then application hangs ..I think due to appending xml nodes to string.Which is the best way to increase performance of loading large files..